# Excel VBA issue : List not appearing during IE automation

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, automation

I was trying to build a simple tool which fills in a 3 field form and downloads the respective file using excel vba

Let me explain the problem I am facing with my code :

Code as follows(works without errors if copy pasted in excel) :

```
Sub ScripHistoryDownloadertry10()

Dim URL As String, Scripcode As String
Dim ie As Object, ieDoc As Object

Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String


StartDate = "01/01/1990"    'Day(#1/1/1990#) & "/" & Month(#1/1/1990#) & "/" & Year(#1/1/1990#)   ' #1/1/1990#
EndDate = "20/01/2014"      'Day(Date) & "/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date)
URL = "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&flag=0"

'Scripcode = "500010"
'I 'll be putting a for loop here to loop through about 5000 values of Scripcode once this issue is solved.

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate URL

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ieDoc = ie.document

'This line below is my problem ===============================================================

ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GetQuote1_txtscrip_code").Value = 500010     'Scripcode

'==========================================================================================

ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate").Value = StartDate
ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").Value = EndDate
ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

'================= Below need to be uncommented to download the file ===========
'ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload").Click
'I'll be inducing a code here to download the file later.
'ie.Quit
'=============================================================================

Set ie = Nothing
Set ieDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have managed to build the code exactly as intended without any errors. The problem is that when we handle the URL page **MANUALLY** and fill the first field in the form(The one i have marked as problem in the code) a small list appears depending on what i enter manually.
But whenever i try to assign the field a value using excel vba IE automation the dropdown list isn't appearing. Can anyone help how to make the list appear and select the topmost value in the list ?

[Here a screenshot how the list looks when filling data manually:](http://min.us/i/m6x0EwbkiEnK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to change the Approach may for me.

After waiting a long for a solution i finally found out a way to the question myself.. :)
First I installed Selenium Wrapper Library that helps us to control the chrome browser with excel vba and then i rewrote the code according to the functions provided by the library ... Same code as above with a different approach :) 
This also helped me tackle the problem of downloading files via internet explorer where one faces a problem to click the download button prompt in IE...
May b this code will be of help to some one .. :)

Here's the code :

```
Sub ScripHistoryDownloaderv2()

Dim selDriver As Object
Dim URL As String, Scripcode As String
Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String

Scripcodez = "500010"
' Set up a loop over here


StartDate = "01/01/1990"
'EndDate = "20/01/2014"
URL = "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&scripcode=" & Scripcodez & "&flag=sp&Submit=G"


dd = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path



Set selDriver = CreateObject("SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver")
selDriver.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com/"
selDriver.Open URL

selDriver.Type "id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate", StartDate
'selDriver.Type "id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate", EndDate
selDriver.findElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
selDriver.Click "id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"
selDriver.clickAndWait "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload"
selDriver.Wait 9000

selDriver.stop


End Sub
```